# Vertical space between two inline-block and a block element

Tags: html, css

```css
.rectangle {
    width: 420px;
    height: 143px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 92px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 92px solid transparent;
    border-left:45px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: inline-block;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div><!--
--><div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Where does it come from? How to get rid of it without negative margins (because on some screens they may overlap).

Comment: it's because of the mismatch between the height of .rectangle and the border-width of .triangle.. you can adjust it to remove the space between the divs

Comment: the reason you have that space is the different vertical-align of your inline blocks - consider using the same one, and the issue will go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answers provide solutions, but not the ***why*** this happens:

```
Some given funny joke
-----^---------^-^
```

In that string I've marked three characters. Those three have so called '[decenders](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-1/type-anatomy/anatomy)' *(e.g.: the loop under the G, the legs under the Y and J)*.
When you declare something `inline-block`, it gets the properties of both `block` and `inline` elements. The inline elements are often text (*e.g. `a` or `span`*), thus have decenders,  thus **your div has room for decenders**.

This is ***why*** setting `line-height:0; font-size:0;` does the trick.

Answer (score 8):

there is a many solution for this

**Solution 0: No Space Between Elements**

```
<ul><li>Item content</li><li>Item content</li><li>Item content</li></ul>
```

**Solution 1:  font-size: 0 on Parent**

```
.inline-block-list { /* ul or ol with this class */
    font-size: 0;
}

.inline-block-list li {
    font-size: 14px; /* put the font-size back */
}
```

**Solution 2:  HTML Comments**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 3:  Negative Margin**

```
.inline-block-list li {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

**Solution 4:  Dropping Closing Angle**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item content</li
 ><li>Item content</li
 ><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

**[more about this](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)**

Comment: Only solution 1 is good. Solution 3 is bad because you should not fix a text problem with a hardcoded margin, as soon as font size increases, this will be wrong. Or if a font is rendered different (eg various browsers).

Comment: And please dont use 4 either, this is very confioussing. I missed what was going on, I would've "fixed" it, breaking the design with it.

Comment: Solution 0 and 2 arent the solution either in this case. Sticking the elements together is good if you want them nexto eachother, but beneath eachother is a different story.

Comment: for anyone doing `ul/li`, make sure you have `display: list-item` for `li` - I had it overridden with `inline-block` and it caused the gaps to appear.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS pseudo element `:after` in this case.

**Check below example:**

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 420px;
  height: 143px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.rectangle:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 92px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 92px solid transparent;
  border-left: 45px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

its because of `line-height`, also, your `.rectangle` was missing 1px in height(143->144)

NOTE: im not sure, if this is a cross-browser, so consider using `float: left` instead

```css
.rectangle {
    width: 420px;
    height: 144px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 92px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 92px solid transparent;
    border-left:45px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: inline-block;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}
.wrapper{
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="rectangle"></div><!--
--><div class="triangle"></div><!--
--><div class="block"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `font-size:0` to parent element