# Space between rows in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a 16x16 grid.
Everything works perfectly except that I have some space between my rows, I can't figure out why.
The spacing between the columns is perfect but the rows have some gap between them.

Here's my code:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("drawingGrid");
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
let cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

function createGrid() {
  makeRows(16);
  makeColumns(16);
}

// create rows
function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  }
}
// create columns
function makeColumns(cellNum) {
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
      let newCell = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
    }
  }
}

createGrid();
```

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>EtchASketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="drawingGrid">
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's what it looks like on chrome:

[image]

Comment: Use `.gridRow { display: flex; }` to fix it.

Comment: @m4n0 's answer is better than anything I was looking at-- as to _why_ the gap is there, that's a bit more mysterious.

Comment: Because there's a default line-height in your row

Comment: @AlexanderNied I suspect the computed `font-size: 16px`.

Comment: The gap is the so called: `inline decender space`. space for letters like y, j, g, p that requires space below the normal base-line.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+vertical+gap+between+inline-block+elements) of [Vertical space between two inline-block and a block element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38520001/4642212).

Comment: vertical-align top to your elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the height of your row:

```
.gridRow{
  max-height:10px;
}
```

or setting the line-height of your row:

```
.gridRow{
  line-height:10px;
}
```

or using flexbox as defined by m4n0.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You can turn the `gridRow` into a flexbox container. You can read the reason behind the space: [Why does my image have space underneath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath) here.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("drawingGrid");
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
let cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

function createGrid() {
  makeRows(16);
  makeColumns(16);
}

// create rows
function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  }
}
// create columns
function makeColumns(cellNum) {
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
      let newCell = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
    }
  }
}

createGrid();
```

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gridRow {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>EtchASketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="drawingGrid">
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```